# How to Get 3 days before date if get date from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a Form where the user fills information about XYZ , with start date and expiry date.when clicking on the button  , the information will save in database. Now I need 3 days before date from the expiry date and need show in the label on a web form ex. the expiry date is 12/12/2012 this date is saved in the database now when the user open his profile there must show expiry date 09/12/2012

I get 3 days before date from current date but not have any idea that how get if the date has come from the database any idea?

you can see in codes in lbltest i show 3 day before date from current date 
and Label1 get date from database

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Enddate from moudetails", con);
SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
DA.Fill(Dt);
if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    lbltest.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Label1.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"].ToString();                
}
```

Comment: Use the DateTime field read from the databse instead of `DateTime.Now`

Comment: Sorry Sir, but its bounce to my head can you please explain how I do?

Comment: In your case, something like `DateTime.Parse(Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"].ToString()).AddDays(-3);` will do.

Comment: `lbltest.Text = Dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Enddate").AddDays(-3).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 2):

If you store dates as string, try using the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) method. Then you will be able to deduct the three days from the date retrieved from database.

Based on comments, another solution that might work is casting the object to datetime:

```
Label1.Text = (Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"] as DateTime).ToString()
```

Comment: happy to help! please mark it as the accepted answer if you don't have any further questions. :) I added another option you might be able to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Convert

```
string dateString = Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"].ToString();
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);

date.AddDays(-3).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method suggested by Sir, ISPain17

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Enddate from moudetails", con);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    DA.Fill(Dt);
    if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string dateString = Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"].ToString();
        //lbltest.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //Label1.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"].ToString();
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Parse(dateString).AddDays(-3).ToString();
    }
```

and its work :D

Comment: you don't need to convert DateTime into a string and then parse a date and then again covert into a string. Check what are you storing into a database. If you are already storing into as a datetime then you can directly use AddDays method.                                                                                                      
   DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
         string asString = now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
         Console.WriteLine(asString);

Comment: Dt.Rows[0]["Enddate"] returns an object as per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_. You need to cast this object to DateTime, that can also work. But it won't be a DateTime without a cast.